# Dynamic interactive line/bezier curve in XPCE Prolog

Tags: graphics, bezier, swi-prolog, xpce

My task is to connect in xpce prolog two squares, each of which equipped with a move_gesture, with a line/bezier curve in such a way that the line is moved along with the objects; does anyone know how this can be done or whether this is possible?

Comment: you could stretch the curve's control points when moving one of the objects while the other stays put. then re-draw the curve.

Comment: I think you need to implement by yourself, or consider that we have Qt available in SWI-Prolog now.